# Ethereum Geth - pending Transactions

Tags: ethereum, geth

My question is: How can I see **pending** transactions in geth and how can I see my transactions at the blocks? I tried it but I can't see them?

I found the Managment API but I also can't see the pending `tx`.
I also tried to check my old transactions from my wallet address and they are also not shown! Do I need to configure geth in any way? I have not changed anything in the config file!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:

- `eth.pendingTransactions`
- `eth.pendingTransactions.length`

[image]

Example from my Geth

[image]

To filter the transactions sent from your address, you can use this snippet:

```
m = 796100 // starting block, it's better not start from 0, it's time consuming
n = eth.blockNumber // the 'latest' block

for (var i = m; i < n; i++) {
    var block = eth.getBlock(i, true);
    for (var j = 0; j < block.transactions.length; j++) {
        if (block.transactions[j].from == "0x...") {
            txs.push(block.transactions[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

In below example, I want to catch all transactions sent from `0xebe78a89cecaf67bb79881d7440ba14486d21b7e` between block number 796100 to latest block (796297):

[image]

Notes:

- Geth works best with one-liner JavaScript code. That's why my JS code above is in one line.
- Bigger and clearer image is available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31lm8.png).

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful, but in my geth I cant see anything like in your first picture.
Do i have to configure my geth in any way?

Comment: AA I think I get it, i can just see my transactions, but i would like to see all pending tx in the Ethereum network

Answer (score 1):

You can go to geth console and execute command "txpool". you'll be able to see the pending queue.